# Is it possible to have a break point on state of an object in intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea, breakpoints, jetbrains-ide, intellij-14, conditional-breakpoint

I have an object and a bunch of functions make some changes to the state of this object (by changing one of its members or a member of its members and so on..). I want to inspect the changes made by each of these functions. Is there a way to have a break point which will halt the program execution whenever something is changed inside this object?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need a field watch point. See [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/types-of-breakpoints.html) and [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/creating-field-watchpoints.html). You will have to set one watch point for each field in which you are interested. I've not used them much so I don't know what impact many of them will have on the performance of your program.

Comment: I have tried it out. But that does not seem to work after the object is created. I wanted a breakpoint for any change in its subojects as well.